# detecting empty fields in XML trough FLASH AS2

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I have this simple XML file, witch I'm calling in a SWF file. This is the code:

```
<goals1>
<minute>32</minute>
<name>Name</name>
<minute>35</minute>
<name>Name2</name>
</goals1>
```

So these nodes are going to be empty. They are even not going to exist. But I'm going to put the paths in to the AS2. So my question is: - What to do to make them not showing "undefined" in the swf file. In other words I need to display content when there is any.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got no whitespace, you'd simply check is that node is empty or not.

```
if (example.nodeValue != '') {
    // Run your stuff
}
```

You could also run a for() based on the length of an xml object to only execute given children.

Something like this:

```
xmlFeed.onLoad = function() {
    // Pre defined and go the depth you need
    parsedXML = xmlFeed.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes;

    for (var i:Number = 1; i <= parsedXML.length; i++) {
        if(parsedXML[i].firstChild.nodevalue != "") {
            // Run your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but in mu case these nods are not going to exist in the first place. So i need to check first is there any nods and if there are to display the content. Any ideas ho to do that ?

Comment: Well basicly the `for()` would run through your <goals1> as many times as there are children. If there are none, none will be fetched.